# Spyder console displaying commented code in the console

Tags: python, ipython, spyder

Can't seem to find any links for information.  Not sure if Spyder setting or what.

Script:

```
print("THIS IS MY TEST SCRIPT")



'''
Why do I print in the console?

'''
```

Console output:

> In[3]: runcell(0, 'C:/Repos/OA/Sandbox/untitled0.py')
>
> THIS IS MY TEST SCRIPT
>
> Out[3]: '\nWhy do I print in the console?\n\n'

Question is why are my commented out lines printing in the console and can I turn it off?

Interesting to me it only prints the last comment.
If I put anything after the comment, it does not print.

Right now, I'm ending my script with print("don't display anything") but I'd rather just turn off the comment display.  Any way to do it?

```
print("THIS IS MY TEST SCRIPT")


'''
I don't print
'''

'''
I print

'''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triple quotes are actually a multi-line string definition but they are commonly used for doc-strings (for functions, classes, modules, etc.). I assume spyder prints the output of the last statement. You can use single-line comments to avoid it: `# comment ...`. Or have something else after the multiline comment.

Comment: lol, I'm new here.  So it just prints the string even though there is no print command?  That's funny. I don't remember it doing this before, not sure how I never knew this.   Anyway, yeah, if I actually create a variable mystr=''' stuffs '''' it doesn't print lol.